# Maximum number of libraries in one web

Tags: document-library, document-center, boundaries

I've been having a look at [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as I'm looking at the options for a document repository with high volume and a rather complex security matrix.

I can see most of the limits I need to start playing with the IA options and pivoting the metadata around but I can't see how many libraries I can have in one site.

The boundaries mention how to get up to 250.000 sites. that's actually more than what I need, but site level might be an option for us. 
I was wondering if I could take it one level down. I was thinking of something like 20.000 libraries in a site.

Has anyone done anything like this? Any tips?

Comment: For the benefit of those who go to both forums, the same question has also been posted at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/20b0fe16-b1a7-4394-9cc9-9f72fd4c9ef5/maximum-number-of-libraries-in-a-web?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: General consensus appears to be to keep below the 2000 items at every level, and I'll keep that in mind, but for the sake of properly documenting my research, it would be nice to know if there's a hard limit

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard limit for doc libraries, there is rather a limit for 60.000.000 items per content database: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ContentDB

"The largest number of items per content database that has been tested on SharePoint Server 2013 is 60 million items, including documents and list items. If you plan to store more than 60 million items in SharePoint Server 2013, you must deploy multiple content databases."